# Including header file in source file of the same name

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c-header

Is it required to include the header file in the corresponding source file if they both have the same name ?

Here is an example of what I mean :

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "display.h"

int main(void)
{
    display("Hello, world!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**display.h**

```c
#ifndef DISPLAY_H
#define DISPLAY_H

void display(char* message);

#endif
```

**display.c**

```c
#include "display.h" // <<< Is this line required
#include <stdio.h>

void display(char* message)
{
    printf("%s\n", message);
}
```

Comment: Yes it is. Btw. the files still have different names. The extension counts as well.

Comment: Normally, each source file defines functions declared in a header.  One common convention is for source file `source.c` to have header `source.h` where `source.h` declares the functions (and types and macros) needed to use the facilities defined in `source.c`.  However, it is feasible for a single header to declare the facilities defined by numerous source files.  The standard C headers are an example of this: `<stdio.h>` declares a lot of functions (and types and macros), but the source for those functions is split among numerous source files, most of which are not named `stdio.c`.

Comment: No, @hko, it is not.  There is no requirement for there even to *be* a header corresponding to each (or any) source.  If there is a header corresponding to a given source (with the conventional contents for such a header) then there are advantages to the source including that header, but there is no requirement for it to do so.

Comment: If you're creating a library of functions that will likely be used together, consider putting together a 'library header' (e.g. `xyzlib.h` for a library XYZ), and then having the component files (`xyzname.c`, `xyzproc.c`, `xyzfile.c`, …) include `xyzlib.h`.  Users of the library will use `#include "xyzlib.h"` or perhaps `#include  "xyz/xylib.h"`, and the source code should use the same notation as users are expected to use.

Comment: While @JohnBollinger says (correctly) "there is no requirement", that should be interpreted with caution.  The functions to be called must be declared before they're used (assuming you use C99 or later, as you should), and the most reliable way to do that is to ensure that: (1) there is a single header that declares each function (though the header will usually declare many functions); (2) each source file that uses any of the functions uses the header; (3) the source file that defines the functions uses the header.  Headers are the glue that holds a project together, ensuring consistency.

Comment: If you use GCC (or Clang), you should use options such as `-Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes` to ensure that functions are declared before being defined (though `static` functions do not have to be pre-declared if they are only used after they are defined in a source file).  You can add options such as `-Wold-style-declaration` and `-Wold-style-definition` to get warnings about `extern int old_func();` and `int old_func() { … }`.  Neither of those provides a function prototype unless you're using C23.  These aren't 100% _necessary_ according to the standard, but they improve quality.

Comment: Thank you very much @JonathanLeffler. I also edited my example because I wrote by mistake the same code in `main.c` and in `display.c`.

Comment: Hi, @John Bollinger, you are right. The way I interpreted the question was if C somehow has a feature that it automatically includes header files if they have the same name as the C file. Which is not the case. But maybe I misinterpreted the question.